# cant find ruby iDE

Tags: ruby

I know its a bad title.

I have just downloaded Ruby from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ because I thought it might be a cool language to learn but I can't find where the IDE is in the folder, is there an IDE with it or not? If so can anyone tell me where it is?

Comment: No, Ruby doesn't come with an IDE

Comment: Ruby is a programing language. they have no IDE,  if you want a IDE you can use rubymine

Comment: ah ok, just wondering because python came with an IDE so i thought ruby might too

Comment: Python doesn't come with an IDE, the pyCharm from intellij automatically downloads python to your computer. Python just gives you a command line toolset.

Comment: python came with IDLE?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. The question could be solved by some research. Also, if you know it's a bad title, then why use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is just the interpreter and doesn't provide any IDE. You can use the editor of your choice like [Atom](https://atom.io/), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or VIM.

However there are also IDEs for ruby, like the awesome [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/)

Comment: i wouldve gone for rubymine but i didnt want to pay for anything

Comment: That's ok, in that case I'd recommend the Atom Editor

Comment: just downloaded it, just trying to get my head round it

Comment: i went for sublime text 3 instead but when i try to build the program it says `'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Sorry but I think you should first learn some basics in using your operating system, a shell and how a interpreter work.

Comment: i selected ruby as the build system then hit builld and then it said that

Comment: Hi, I have been using RubyMine, But you have said some other editor like Atom,Sublime Text, May I know can we debug through this editors?

Answer (score 1):

The state of Ruby IDEs in 2016 is very sad, the original question does not deserve to be rated down as it addresses a valid point.

Except Intellij Rubymine, there is no actively maintained, fully featured IDE available for Ruby that supports Intellisense (or comparable functionality) and fast, visual debugging.

Unless you shell out more than USD200 in the first year and still more than USD100 each subsequent year to Intellij, you'll have to do with Emacs, Vi(m), Atom, Visual Studio Code etc. like solutions for source code editing without Intellisense support and rely on rdebug, ruby-debug-ide (super slow!) or my favorite debugging console: pry.

I am hoping for someone to enable Intellisense for Ruby in Visual Studio Code and provide a decent debugging plugin there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many IDEs which support Ruby. There is Ruby Mine, from Intellij, Netbeans has a Ruby setting. Atom has a Ruby setting and is my favorite right now. I'm sure Visual Studio and Visual Studio code both have Ruby plugins.

Typically programming languages do not come with a dedicated IDE, because IDEs only help you a little, technically you can just use Notepad. So, it's up to you to find one that you like.